# layout_constrainedWidth not working properly

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I’ve got EditText and TextView in my ConstraintLayout. TextView displays content of EditText.

On input I need EditText to expand untill the middle of the screen and TextView to follow it and fill the second half.

[image]

I set guideline at 50%, and use wrap_content и layout_constrainedWidth for both widgets.

Here is my xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.manualuser.android.polygon.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:minWidth="1dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I get is when TextView reaches end of the screen it supersedes EditText  to the left.

[image]

It works as needed when I set TextView layout_width to match_constraint. But how do I make it work with wrap_content?

Comment: give layout_width 0dp

Comment: @wick.ed it works fine with match_constraint but why wrap_content is not working?

Comment: Don't set width to 0dp. constrainedWidth is meant to be used with wrap_content. If you use 0dp then it does nothing.

Comment: I am also running into this issue.  Has a bug been filed?  The source code looks like it uses EXACTLY instead of AT_MOST with constrainedWidth.

Answer (score 12):

I had a very similar issue.
Basically what I observed is that it works weird when used with `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` set to `0.0`.

so if you change

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
```

to

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.001"
```

It should work (at least it worked for me)

Please report it as a bug if you have time. It's an issue even in `2.0.0-beta2`

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change, the width of horizontalScrollView to 0dp or match constraint. Then it would not overshadow the EditText and both will take up the half of the spaces. Still, for the purpose of checking, I am putting the revised code below.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.manualuser.android.polygon.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: looks like this code does not include the change you suggested?

Comment: @TimCastelijns sorry horizontalScrollView width to match constraint or 0dp.

Comment: Yes, it works with match_constraint. But my question is why wrap_content pared with layout_constrainedWidth not working the same way. Why scrollView doesn't respect left constraint when it reaches end of the screen?

Comment: I need to clarify why I want to use wrap_content: what if i add another widget right after TextView that follows it and become right constraint to it when reaches end of the screen? Match_constraint is of no use here?

Comment: @AlekseyBulin Well, I think match_constraint would work because when you add another widget you can add textView's right constraint to the new widget's left constraint and widget right constarint to screen end. That could work, and plus when we specify match_constarint it shows 0dp i.e. it would take only that much of space that is left or given to it accordingly. Hope it clarifies. If you need I could help in more modification to this code.

Comment: @harshjain this way last widget would stick to the end of the screen and wouldn't follow TextView on input. But i would like to see your code.